# Page manager module is unable to enable taxonomy/term/%term because some other module already has overridden with 

Tags: drupal

I'm using drupal 6.20 Along with some modules including Panels, Views, And some others ..

The thing is, i am getting this error whenever i try to enable the Taxonomy Override page that Panels provides, I modified it and all, i just can't seem to find a way to enable it whatever i do!

The error i get is:

```
Page manager module is unable to enable taxonomy/term/%term because some other module already has overridden with .
```

That's what i get, now i'm usually used to this kind of error, but Drupal always provides the name of the function or module preventing the change at the end .. This time, all i get is that Dot at the end ..

Can you please help me solve the issue?

Comment: This is not an error, but an informative message. It explains that there can be only one module that rewrites the taxonomy_term pages. In other words: it tells you you are using incompatible modules. The solution is to use either one of the modules, not both.

Comment: so my only solution is to download the site with all its data and start disabling Modules until i find the culprit? but why did this occur all of a sudden like that? i didn't add any module lately ..

But i will try it out and see what happens.. thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may have a view overriding the taxonomy pages. that would be my first place to check.

Comment: you are right! Thanks to you! all is fine now :), Gokul N K 's answer was reasonable, but partially did the job, this fixed it! God I'm soo stupid !

Answer (score 2):

Download [util](http://drupal.org/project/util) and edit the module weights so that page manager has a higher weight. Check out the default [module weights](http://drupal.org/node/110238) and change the weight accordingly.

Comment: That solved it !!! Thaaaaanks !! i just set the Page manager to -99 Weight and that did the job .. Sorry i couldn't give you a vote up, but it needs 15+ Reputation which i don't have .. as soon as i have it, i will give you the thumbs up definitely :D

Comment: Even if you get that you can't vote up for the answer you accept ;)

Comment: oh! i didn't know that! :( .. anyway, you really saved me here :D

Answer (score 2):

When enabled, the Taxonomy Term View page display takes over the default Drupal path (/taxonomy/term/% ) for displaying taxonomy terms.  Simply change the Taxonomy Term View's page display path settings from '/taxonomy/term/%' to something like 'view/taxonomy/term/%'.

Create a Content Pane display and set the Argument Input settings to Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) source = 'From context' and set the Required context to 'Term Id'.  This allows Panels to pass the term argument into the Taxonomy Term View's Content Pane display.

Now, simply add the Views Content Pane in a panel and you are done.